# Quota restriction error when attempting to create a GCE image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, vmdk

I am trying to create a GCE image from an VMDK file but I am getting a quota error. None of the quotas on my quota limit page are at or near 100%.

Which quota or restriction am I hitting here and why?

```
> gcloud compute images import cloudimg --source-file=gs://bucket/cloudimg.vmdk

Copying [gs://bucket/cloudimg.vmdk] to [gs://proj-us-east1/tmpimage/cloudimg.vmdk]...done.
WARNING: Importing image. This may take up to 2 hours.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.import) FAILED_PRECONDITION: generic::failed_precondition: due to quota restrictions, cannot run builds in this region
```